# Complete incremental phone sync

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, sync

I have two samsung galaxy s2 models and I want them to sync with each other completely, either over wifi or usb. I usually only use one at a time. Is it possible or is there an app already for that?

Comment: What is it you want to sync? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: also: are your devices rooted?

Comment: I want to sync all the settings and app data for each phone. basically i want mirror images of my phones. no my phones are not rooted.